# tag an equation

Tags: equations, xetex, arabic, tag, reflection

I want to give a name to an equation which is "the reverse of ن"

i'm using polyglossia  when I write

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titleps}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.geometric}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,AutoFakeSlant=-0.03]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}




\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{n}{\tag{\reflectbox{ن}}}
a=b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

it gives me many errors at end{equation}

the first is

```
undefined control sequence.
\bidiGscale@box...\fi\leavevmode\def\Gscale@y{#2}\se...\end{equation}
```

but if a delete \tag there is no error , how to de please to give this name to the equation?

Thank you

Comment: You only provided an untestable fragment, I completed it to a document for testing but I get no error, please edit the example so it makes an error and show the error that you get (the form you show is not the format of a tex error message)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i edited the message

Comment: The posted code does not produce the error you state it produces an undefined command error `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...(\kern \z@ \ignorespaces \eflectbox 
                                                  {ن}\unskip \@@italiccorr )...
l.42 \end{equation}
`  because of the typo `\eflectbox` instead of `\reflectbox`

Comment: I get no error with `\protect\reflectbox`. The parentheses are reversed, though.

Comment: this code is not the first , I reduce it for the question

Comment: @egreg is there a way to obtain a completely reversed ن